# Fancybox 2 iframe not working correctly in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I'm having an issue with Fancybox 2.0 and Internet Explorer. It works fine on all other browsers.

In IE is like the lightbox div comes on top of the iframe and I can't click any buttons.

Also the position in the page is different than on other browsers.

This are the parameters I'm using to call it

```
$('.fancybutton').fancybox({
        type      : 'iframe',
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : true,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '80%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
});
```

Any help would be very much appreciated

I'm opening the iframe with a normal link on an anchor tag

**UPDATE**

I added the DOCTYPE and the iframe is being opened fine in all browsers but...
Inside this iframe i have a number of links, this works as a popup menu. The links are simple anchor tags, but when I click on the links in IE nothing happens. It works perfect on any other browsers :(

Cheers,
Federico

Comment: do you think we can see a link? it seems like there is nothing wrong with the code above but that says nothing. There a list of things you can start doing: check for javascript errors (IE is much more strict than other browsers); check you have a proper `DOCTYPE` (fancybox doesn't play well in IE quirks mode); check for CSS conflict issues (general CSS declarations like `div {position: absolute}` ... use specificity instead `div#myDiv {position: absolute}`), etc, etc, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying as it turns out it was the doctype !!! :)

Comment: This is like a menu popup, but the submenus wont open in IE. I need to open them in the same iframe but it does nothing in IE 8 and it shows page not found in IE 9. :(

Comment: could you show a link then? ... also make sure that the page that opens in fancybox also has a correct `DOCTYPE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out I was missing the DOCTYPE as JFK suggested.

I added it at the top and it now works fine on all browsers

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Thanks!

Comment: At the top of what? Your page containing the link that opens the fancybox, or the fancybox content page?

Comment: Logically should be in both spots. Fancybox iFrame is a standalone page by itself.