# fancybox.js not working properly on internet explorer 11

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2, fullpage.js

I'm creating a project that using `fullpage.js` with `fancybox.js` function on it. It's work perfectly on modern browser like Chrome, Mozila, Safari ect. When it been tested on Internet Explorer 11, it show a different result where when click close/overlay function while the fancybox is open, it's brings back to the top section `fp-viewing-0` .

Try insert this code but still not showing the best result, [Fancybox 2 iframe not working correctly in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565443/fancybox-2-iframe-not-working-correctly-in-ie)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

And why it works on jsfiddle but not in the server side?

Any tricks to solve this issue? Here's my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1dw1ws1a/)